# How can I fix the homepage header image displaying incorrectly on iPhone 13 while hosted on an Apache2 server with React and CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, apache

I am hosting my react website on an apache2 server. My website is responsive and my homepage image (the problem) looks great on desktop. When I do the mobile view option on firefox and even chrome it works and looks great.

However when I host it on the server it looks great on desktop/mobile view on desktop, but on my iphone 13 the homepage header only shows the top portion of the image. I was thinking its either a caching issue or I have a css file not loading properly.

So to pretty much summarize this up it looks good on my local machine and desktop but when it is on an actual mobile phone the image looks funky.

I am fairly new to hosting websites and this is the first problem I have had. If someone could help me out that would be great!

I have tried changing the css styling for the image but it looks great on my local machine? Then on the server on mobile it looks bad. If needed I can upload my code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.